# Use Dropdown List to Update Pricing Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I have a pricing table which contains some variables that depend on a dropdown list selection. The [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/r48fjcev/) shows the desired outcome.

The desired outcome is dependable on the drop-down selection. As a selection is picked, then the following changes should take place in the table:

1. The "Item Cost" should display the price selected.
2. The "Total" price should be multiplied by the "Qty." to display the total shipping cost.
3. The grand "Total" should be the sum of the total column that includes Product + Shipping Costs.

Here's the dropdown options:

```
<div class="input-group full-width">
    <span class="input-group-addon main-color hidden-sm hidden-xs">$</span>
    <select id="shippingmethod" class="selectpicker form-control shipping-method" name="shippingmethod" aria-label="Shipping Method" tabindex="">
       <option value="" selected="">Selet a Shipping Method</option>
       <option value="2.95">US Mail - $2.95</option>
       <option value="3.50">Priority Mail - $3.50</option>
       <option value="4.67">Fedex - $4.67</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The table is as follows:

```
<table id="product-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Item</th>
            <th class="text-center">Qty.</th>
            <th class="text-center">Item Cost</th>
            <th class="text-center">Tax</th>
            <th class="text-right">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="pt5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td class="qty">2</td>
            <td class="item-cost">$10.00</td>
            <td class="tax">$0.68</td>
            <td class="total">$10.68</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="pt5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipping Cost</td>
            <td class="qty red">1</td>
            <td class="item-cost red">$2.95</td>
            <td class="tax">$0.00</td>
            <td class="total red">$5.90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="pt5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="product-totals">
            <td colspan="4"></td>
            <td class="total red">$13.02</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would appreciate any help I can get regarding this scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want changes on the client-side to update some content, you'll need to use javascript/jQuery .change() function on the element you want to observe.
[See here for more details](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

in your case, this would be:

```
$("#shippingmethod").change(function() {
    // start by fetching the value of the selected option
    var shippingPrice = $(this).val();
    // do some other stuff to get other values, calculate, and display results
});
```

That other stuff you'll need to do will include using [.html() function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to change the values displayed in some elements of your table, like so: `$("#shippingprice").html("$" + shippingPrice);`

Note that the .html() func can also fetch a value form an element:

```
// Get the value displayed inside the id="shippingqty" td
var shippingQty = $("#shippingqty").html();
```

Please note however that this will provide you with a String type var, you'll need to use `parseFloat(shippingQty);` to make some maths with it.

Edit: As of your comment, there's a quick  (and somewhat dirty) fiddle for you to examine (Note the comments in the html). Regarding javascript, best place to start id probably the [javascript basics @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics).

```js
$("#shippingmethod").change(function() {
  // Get the value from dropdown
  var shippingPrice = $(this).val()
  // Get the value from id="shippingqty" td content
  var shippingQty = $("#shippingqty").html();
  // get the value from id="producttotal" td content
  var prodPriceWithSymbol = $("#producttotal").html();

  // remove the $ symbol from prodPriceWithSymbol text 
  var productTotal = prodPriceWithSymbol.substring(1, prodPriceWithSymbol.length);
  // strings to floats, multiply, round to 2 decimals
  var shippingTotal = (parseFloat(shippingPrice) * parseFloat(shippingQty)).toFixed(2);
  // strings to float, add, round to 2 decimals
  var grandTotal = (parseFloat(shippingTotal) + parseFloat(productTotal)).toFixed(2);

  // Set id="shippingprice" td content
  $("#shippingprice").html("$" + shippingPrice);
  // set id="shippingtotal" td content
  $("#shippingtotal").html("$" + shippingTotal);
  // set id='grandtotal" td content
  $("#grandtotal").html("$" + grandTotal);
});
```

```css
.pr8 {
  padding-right: 8px;
}
.red {
  font-weight: 600!important;
  color: #ff0000;
}
.spacer,
.help-block {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0 7px;
}
.fw6 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
table#product-list {
  width: 100%;
}
table#product-list thead tr th {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #0080a6 !important;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #0080a6;
  padding: 5px 2px 8px 2px;
}
table#product-list tbody {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333 !important;
}
table#product-list tbody tr td:first-child {
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: left !important;
}
table#product-list tbody tr td {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: right !important;
}
table#product-list tbody tr td:last-child {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: right !important;
}
table#product-list tbody tr#product-totals {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
table#product-list tbody tr#product-totals td:last-child {
  border-top: dotted 1px #0080a6;
  padding: 4px 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #0080a6;
}
table#product-list tbody tr td.qty {
  text-align: center !important;
}
table#product-list tbody tr td.item-cost {
  padding: 0 4px 0 0;
}
table#product-list tbody tr td.tax {
  margin: 0 5px 0 3px;
}
table#product-list tbody tr td.total {
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Added jQuery loading -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ReviewShippingAndPayment" name="ReviewShippingAndPayment" method="post" action="/Distributor/Shop/Product-List">
  <div class="container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 p0">
    <div class="pl8 bbcustom p0">
      <h2 class="page-header"><i class="fa fa-cube pr8 hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>Shipping Method Selection</h2>
      <p>
        The desired outcome is driven by the "<span class="fw6">Select a Shipping Method</span>" dropdown.<br /><br />When a shipping method is selected, then the "Item Cost" should be multiplied by the "Qty." and displayed in the Shipping Cost Total
        column.<br /><br />Such selection should also update the final cost that include the Product Cost + Total Shipping.
      </p>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 p0">
      <div class="shipping-method-container">
        <div class="field-wrapper">
          <div class="input-group full-width">
            <span class="input-group-addon main-color hidden-sm hidden-xs">$</span>
            <select id="shippingmethod" class="selectpicker form-control shipping-method" name="shippingmethod" aria-label="Shipping Method" tabindex="">
              <!-- Added value="0" here -->
              <option value="0" selected="">Selet a Shipping Method</option>
              <option value="2.95">US Mail - $2.95</option>
              <option value="3.50">Priority Mail - $3.50</option>
              <option value="4.67">Fedex - $4.67</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <hr style="margim:0px;padding:0;" />
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <table id="product-list">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Item</th>
            <th class="text-center">Qty.</th>
            <th class="text-center">Item Cost</th>
            <th class="text-center">Tax</th>
            <th class="text-right">Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="pt5"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td class="qty">1</td>
            <td class="item-cost">$10.00</td>
            <td class="tax">$0.68</td>
            <td class="total" id="producttotal">$10.68</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="pt5"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Shipping Cost</td>
            <!-- Added id here -->
            <td class="qty red" id="shippingqty">1</td>
            <!-- Added id here -->
            <td class="item-cost red" id="shippingprice">$2.95</td>
            <!-- May add an id to be accessed if needed -->
            <td class="tax">$0.00</td>
            <!-- Added id here -->
            <td class="total red" id="shippingtotal">$5.90</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="pt5"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="product-totals">
            <td colspan="4"></td>
            <!-- Added id here -->
            <td class="total red" id="grandtotal">$13.02</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I really don\'t where to start with javascript?  Can you at least refer me to an example so I can try to figure things out?